# Why is the rotation about COM?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, reference-frames

Suppose a ring is given to us with no hinge as such. Now a bullet comes and strikes the ring and **gets embedded in the ring**.

The ring will now have linear momentum and some rotation going on. Okay, the question is about the axis of rotation. Intuitively it seems that the rotation will be about the [COM](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/centre_of_mass#Noun) of the system. But is there any formal justification to this as to why does it rotate about the COM and not any other point. Everything of course is frictionless.

[image: Here is a picture for reference...everything of course is frictionless]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If the rotation happened around another point, then the COM would be moving around that point in a circle.

This would mean that the COM was accelerating - without any external force and that's not possible.

Comment: ohhhhhhh popped my mind open. Thanks !

Comment: @ chittaranjan rout  Glad it helped

Comment: This is super intuitive! I never thought of it that way. Awesome answer!